# PHP Laravel Gallery split array into 3 columns

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would like to have this effect:

```
<div class="w3-third">Images tags here</div>
<div class="w3-third">Images tags here</div>
<div class="w3-third">Images tags here</div>
```

**PHP**

```
$images = Image::where('gallery_id', $id)->get();    
$list = [];
foreach ($images as $image) {
    array_push($list, $image->file_path);
}
$list = array_chunk($list, 3);    
return view('gallery.gallery')
->with([
    'gallery' => $gallery,
    'images' => $list
]);
```

And I want to push images from this list into those 3 columns.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view iterate over subarrays of `images` and subsubarrays of each `images` subarray:

```
@foreach ($images as $group)
<div class="w3-third">
    @foreach ($group as $item)
    {{ $item }}
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```